# Symfont 2.3 + FOSRestBundle

Tags: symfony, fosrestbundle, symfony-2.3

I am trying to follow the tutorial ## but am running into an issue.
I am receiving the following exception:

```
Call to undefined method Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Builder\NodeBuilder::fixXmlConfig() in DIR\vendor\jms\serializer-bundle\JMS\SerializerBundle\DependencyInjection\Configuration.php line 46
```

Does anyone know what is going on?

I have enabled both required bundles:

```
new JMS\SerializerBundle\JMSSerializerBundle($this),
new FOS\RestBundle\FOSRestBundle(),
```

I'm guessing that one of the bundles is not updated to 2.3 as of yet maybe?

Comment: Does your xml have errors in it? Also check your composer.json against the symfony standard and make sure that you are using similar versions of the bundles. https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/master/composer.json

Comment: I have no xml config, everything is yml based or annotation. composer.json is almost identical as the symfony one, i just have "friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle": "0.12.0",
        "jms/serializer-bundle": "@dev", extra

Comment: Yeah i tried installing jms serializer with symfony 2.3.0 and it throws me errors as well. It seems like one of its dependents di-extra-bundle hasnt been updated for 2.3.0 yet and still only work on up to 2.2.1

Answer (score 4):

If you use the **dev-master** branch for both dependencies you can get it up and running.

composer.json

```
"require": {
    ...
    "friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle": "0.12.0",
    "jms/serializer-bundle": "dev-master",
    "jms/di-extra-bundle": "dev-master"
},
```

AppKernel.php

```
new JMS\SerializerBundle\JMSSerializerBundle($this),
new FOS\RestBundle\FOSRestBundle(),
```

This seems to have sorted it for me.

Comment: Why `dev-master` instead of a specific version.

Comment: At the time of writing no specific version worked. As of now this is working fine without the need for dev-master.